# How do I compile variadic templates conditionally?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

Is there a macro that tells me whether or not my compiler supports variadic templates?

```
#ifdef VARIADIC_TEMPLATES_AVAILABLE

template<typename... Args> void coolstuff(Args&&... args);

#else

???

#endif
```

If they are not supported, I guess I would simulate them with a bunch of overloads. Any better ideas? Maybe there are preprocessor libraries that can ease the job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the current version of Boost defines BOOST_NO_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES if variadic templates are unavailable.  This is provided by `boost/config.hpp`; see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_possible_c__0x_features) for config.hpp documentation.

If variadic templates are unavailable, then you'll probably have to simulate them with a bunch of overloads, as you said.  The [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library can help here; it's designed to automate all sorts of repetitive source code, including template overloads.  You can search the Boost source trees for BOOST_NO_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES for examples on using it to simulate variadic templates.

Comment: I would combine your approach with Niels': propose an interface with many overloads of various arities thanks to Boost.Preprocessor which wraps the parameters into a `Boost.Fusion` container (tuple, vector, etc...) that is then passed to a single template class expecting it in which the actual implementation is done. The idea is simply to reduce the amount of code in the macros to ease debugging :)

Answer (score 8):

Maybe: `#ifndef BOOST_NO_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES`?

---

If variadic templates are not supported, you might think of using the boost tuple library:

```
template<typename Tuple> void coolstuff(Tuple&& args);
```

And:

```
coolstuff(boost::make_tuple(1, 2, 3));
```